# Visual Studio Code with React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, module

I am trying to use React with MS Visual Studio  Code. If I ran the program from the terminal, I get following error message: "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

If I run the program without terminal, it takes me to the browser (Firefox) and gives "File not found" error message.

Not sure how the above two are connected. Is this is a problem with node installation, location of my files (where I do the actual programming), or perhaps is has something to do with Firefox debugger.

Kindly ask for help.
Many thanks.

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react-dom";


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>Test div</div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("App"));
```

I am also providing a code to my .html, in case it is relevant:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/Dejan/Kalkulator/calc.css">
    
</head>

<body>

<h1 id="test">Testing the system</h1>
<script src="/src/Dejan/Kalkulator/calc.js"></script>
</body>
<div id="App"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey Deyan doesn't add  into the HTML file, because react will automatically handle that, and also don't use CSS in HTML it will cause weird behavior at the end.
>
> And don't put App div outside of the body tag. Because inside that div your whole react app will be fitted.

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react-dom";
import "./Dejan/Kalkulator/calc.css"; // and add css like this I don't know your file path use the correct I put randomly.


 class App extends React.Component {
   render() {

    return (
        <div>Test div</div>
       );
      }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("App"));


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Calculator</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="App"></div>
</body>
```